# vectors and collinear points

Tags: vectors

I study maths as a hobby in my retirement. I am looking at vectors and collinear points.

My textbook says the following:

If three points, A, B and C with corresponding position vectors **a**, **b** and **c** are collinear, then AC:CB must be in some ratio, say *l*:*m*.

[image]

Hence $c=\frac{ma+lb}{l+m}$ - I understand this part. It is what my book calls the Section Formula.

Rearranged:

$(l+m)c=ma+lb$

so  $ma +lb-(l+m)c=0$

If this is written $\alpha a+\beta b+\gamma c=0$ then

$\alpha + \beta +\gamma = 0$

This last part is the part I don't follow.

Why should $\alpha + \beta +\gamma = 0$?

(Apologies for not marking vectors in bold. I can't find I way to do this within brackets).

Comment: Is $\alpha = m, \beta=l, \gamma = -(l+m)$?

Comment: Because $\alpha$ is $m$, $\beta$ is $l$, and $gamma$ is $-(l+m)$.

Comment: For boldface, just use \bf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This last part is to be understood as follows:

Suppose you have 3 vectors $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c}$ from the 2D plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are not colinear, *i.e.* the associated points A, B and C are different.

We know that there always exists real numbers $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ such that at least one of them is different than 0 and that they satisfy $$\alpha\mathbf{a} + \beta\mathbf{b} + \gamma\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{0}.$$ (Here, $\mathbf{0}$ is to be understood as a vector. This claim can be justified later if needed.)

You then have the following equivalence:
$$\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 0 \text{ with } \alpha \neq 0, \beta\neq 0, \gamma \neq 0 \ \Leftrightarrow\  \text{the points A, B and C are colinear.}$$

Regarding the proof, the reverse implication $\Leftarrow$ is already proven in your question. We just need to prove the direct implication $\Rightarrow$.

Suppose we have $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 0$. Let us compute:
$$\vec{AB} = \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{a}$$
$$\vec{AC} = \mathbf{c} - \mathbf{b} = \frac{-\alpha\mathbf{a} - \beta \mathbf{b}}{\gamma} - \mathbf{b} = \frac{\alpha\mathbf{a} + \beta \mathbf{b}}{\alpha + \beta} - \mathbf{a} = \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} \mathbf{b} - \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} \mathbf{a} $$
So that finally:
$$\vec{AC} = \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} (\mathbf{b} - \mathbf{a}) = \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} \vec{AB}$$
which proves that the points are colinear.